# Relative sizes in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

When working with HTML/CSS, to style a layout I like to use the units `vw`, `em` and `%`, I rarely use `px` unit. The reason for me is that the user might change the font size for better readability or the user is using a different device or browser, which might have a different screen size or a different default font size.

```css
.example {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 2em;
}
```

In SwiftUI, all I can find is the `CGFloat` given to me by the `GeometryProxy`. Apple seems to know what system size to use when using the `padding(nil)` modifier or omitting the `spacing` in a `HStack` or `VStack`. But I can't figure out how to get those values.

I've seen some complex solutions, but my app requires padding quite a lot. Now I can pass a calculated relative padding down from my parent view to the children and the children of those and, and and. However, that seems to be extremely wrong. Having an `ObservableObject` holding a value like that also seems like a bad practice.

Having a `GeometryReader` in every child view is also not possible, because `GeometryReader` takes up all the space, which I don't want with my child views because they should be as high as their content.

Am I overlooking something, or what is the best way to do this?

## TL;DR

Are there any relative units available in SwiftUI for sizes (like `em` or `vw` in CSS) without passing a `GeometryProxy` down to every child view? I cannot use `GeometryReader` in every child view because it breaks my layout. Or, how to get the default system padding size?

Comment: Apple has different approach - idea is to "not use" explicit, hardcoded, sizes (even relative) *at all*, and the layout engine will decide by itself (depending on content & current space) how to construct UI. That is why there are such things as `padding()`, `xStack()`, `Font.title`, `.layoutPriority`, etc... and `GeometryProxy` - for the rest of us. ))

Comment: To avoid passing the size to children and nested children one by one, and to avoid having an `ObservableObject` to hold a size related value, you could set your padding/size as an environment value for a custom environment key on the whole hierarchy of views: https://lostmoa.com/blog/CustomEnvironmentValuesInSwiftUI/

Comment: @Asperi I was afraid of that. It sounds great, but in reality my app would not be so intuitive if I let the layout engine do its magic. In one of the newer tutorials Apple uses hardcoded sizes as well, not relative. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @NataliaPanferova Thanks for your comment! That is indeed an idea for a workaround, although it would have been nice if there was a more "SwiftUI-native" way.